# Error Installing Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, installation, formatting, reinstall

I'm trying to reinstall windows XP, when I boot to a windows XP disk I get the normal blue screen which runs through installing drivers, then after these drivers are installed, I see at the botton some text that say something like "Windows is starting.." then I get a blue screen of death which says something close to:

> A problem has been detected and Windows has been shut down to prevent damage to your computer.
>
> Check for viruses, remove newly installed HDs or HD controllers, check your HD to make sure it is properly configured and terminated.
>
> Run CHKDSK /F to check for HD corruption, then restart.
>
> Technical information: `STOP 0x0000007B (0xF78D2524, 0xC000034, 0x0000000, 0x0000000)`

I've run CHKDSK and tried again, but that did not help. There probably is a virus on the machine, it's not mine though so I have no idea.. and who knows if it's actually a virus causing this issue..

Anyone have any recommendations?

---

**UPDATE**: [This page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324103) seems to indicate that it's a virus in the boot sector, I'm trying to find out a good way to get rid of it now.. help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IT's not a boot sector virus. You booted from the CD -- the boot sector never got read.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have had this issue building laptops at work.

To resolve it, in the BIOS settings I changed the SATA Operation settings from AHCI or RAID to ATA mode.

Next time you boot from the CD you should not get the BSOD.

Comment: It looks like my options are "AHCI", "RAID", and "IDE". It's currently set to "RAID".

Comment: I would try changing the setting to ACHI, if this does not work then IDE.

Comment: IDE did the trick, TYVM!!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that you are reinstalling the OS, it is more likely that you need a hard drive controller driver.  Go to the manufacturer's website, look for the controller driver, download it and try and load it during the portion of the OS when it asks you to press F6 to load special drivers.

Comment: 7B is INACCESSABLE_BOOT_DEVICE. I.e. setup can't get to the CDRom drive. Probably needs a SATA driver rather than a HDD driver

Comment: The probability is that the hard drive is a SATA.  As seen above, he has a controller that can operate in RAID/ACHI or other modes.  Windows XP being an older OS does not have the drivers necessary so after installing and transfering the files, upon boot, XP tried to load a hard drive driver and couldn't find one matching the hardware.  He can either change the mode, hopefully to IDE, the load the OS again, load the AHCI driver and change to it, or load the driver during OS install either by slipstreaming or F6.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was only, that I used an usb stick to boot. The usb stick caused the error. After burning an bootable cd, it works.